# Generics and inherited types in C#

Tags: c#, generics, inheritance

I'm a little confused about the best way to handle this particular situation. I'm not 100% confident with using generics yet.

I have a class, `Model`, and it has two derived types, `3DModel` and `2DModel`.

I have an abstract property in `Model` of class `View`, which also has two derived types, `3DView` and `2DView`.

When `3DModel` calls the `View` property, I'd like `3DView` returned, which I understand is where the generics come in (currently the 2D and 3D versions just have their own properties with the derived types).

My problem is that to do this I think I need to change `Model` to `Model<TView>` and then provide a where in `3DModel` and `2DModel`. This requires changing every use of `Model`, `2DModel` and `3DModel` to accommodate this though, and it's used absolutely everywhere (including, as far as I can tell, making it impossible to convert instances of `Model` to either `3DModel` or `2DModel`).

Am I right in thinking this is the only way to implement this? It seems like a lot of extra code for something so simple.

Edit:

Some example code

```
public class View
{    
}

public class 3DView : View
{
}

public class Model
{
    public abstract View _view {get; set;}
}

public class 3DModel : Model
{
    public override 3DView _view {get; set;}
}
```

I get the Visual Studio error "Cannot change return type when overriding property".

Comment: From your description you have a classic case of polymorphism not generics.  Generics are a generic programming technic.  What you describe is a is overriding relationship.

Comment: Okay, but I guess that isn't allowed on C#? At least not without some workaround?

Comment: It is look at virtual functions and overriding.  C# is a full featured oo language.

Comment: But the return types of the properties in the derived class are different. I get an error when I try and change it, am I missing something?

Comment: And now we get to the root of the [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). You have an error in your code. Please post the relevant code, include an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Do you want to have property `View` to be of types `3DView`, `2DView` for `3DModel` and `2DModel` classes respectively? Or it is ok to have property `View` to be of type `View` everywhere, but return objects of `3DView` and `2DView` in `3DModel` and `2DModel`?

Comment: The former, I think. I'd like the type of the property in the derived class to be the derived type for the View. So 3DModels View property would return a 3DView.

Comment: You can still return objects of `3DView` type from the property of `View` type as long as `3DView` inherits `View`, so it is still not quite clear what you are trying to achieve. Please, provide a minimal complete verifiable example as @mason suggested.

Comment: Hmm. I have in Model: public abstract View _view and in 3DModel I have public override 3DView _view which is giving me the VS error "Cannot change type when overriding property."

Comment: Why not just define the `View` property in the derived `3DModel` and `2DModel` classes?

Comment: @rerun, pendantic hat on here: generics is a form of polymorphism: it's parametric polymorphism

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two approaches here, I think.

First, you may use usual inheritance:

```
public abstract class View 
{
    public abstract void Hello();
}

public class _3DView : View
{
    public override void Hello() 
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Hello from 3D View");
    }
}

public class _2DView : View
{
    public override void Hello() 
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Hello from 2D View");
    }
}

public abstract class Model
{
    public abstract View { get; }
}

public _3DModel : Model 
{
    public override View  { get { return new _3DView; } }
}

public _2DModel : Model 
{
    public override View  { get { return new _2DView; } }
}

Model model = new _3DModel();
model.View.Hello(); // have "Hello from 3D View"

Model anotherModel = new _2DModel();
anotherModel.View.Hello();  // have "Hello from 2D View"
```

This way you can work with models and views polymorphically and still can cast a `View` to, say, `_3DView` when needed.

Or you can use generics like this:

```
// Views are declared the same way

public abstract class Model<TView>
    where TView: View
{
    public abstract TView View { get; }
}

public class _3DModel : Model<_3DView>
{
    public override _3DView View { get { return new _3DView; } }
}

public class _2DModel : Model<_2DView>
{
    public override _2DView View { get { return new _2DView; } }
}

Model<_3DView> model = new _3DModel();
model.View.Hello();
```

The downsize of generics approach is that you can’t say something like this:

```
Model model = new _3DModel();
```

since there is no single model parent. To my mind, generics approach makes no sense in this situation.

Comment: I think you may be right. I'll have to stick with inheritance and casting. I'll mark this as correct. Thankyou for taking the time to write all this up.

Comment: You may also have a look at @Maarten’s answer. It provides a kind of combination of these two approaches.

Answer (score 4):

You can keep your non-generic Model class, and introduce an abstract generic Model class.

```
public abstract class Model<TView> : Model where TView : View
{
    public new TView _view
    {
        get { return base._view as TView; }
        set { base._view = value; }
    }
}

public class View3D : View { }

public class Model3D : Model<View3D> { }

public class View2D : View { }

public class Model2D : Model<View2D> { }
```

Answer (score 1):

The best solution for me is to use generic class, indeed.

You have another solution (more ugly), is create an interface for your views, and define your method View() as following :

```
public IView View()
```

Then you can eventually  create specific properties in your 2D/3D models :

```
public 2DView 2DView()
{
    return this.View() as 2DView;
}
```

But you can't have the same result than with a generic class...